# Storing Movie Sequels and Prequels

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Given that I have a model that stores movies, what would be the best way to specify relationships such as movie sequels and prequels?

I'd like to access these relationships using simple accessors such as `movie.sequels` (which would return an ordered list of movies that are sequels to `movie`) and `move.prequels`.

I've considered using a `has_many :through` relationship with a secondary model but how would I maintain movie sequence?

Or could there be a better methodology entirely?

Comment: If sequels and prequels aren't ordered, why not simply `has_many`?

Comment: The accessors would preferably return an ordered list.  I updated the question to better indicate this.

Comment: So do you consider "sequel" relationship to be transitive? E.g. is "Matrix: Revolutions" a sequel to "Matrix", or only to "Matrix: Reloaded"?

Comment: It would be ideal if the final result of movie.sequels lists every successive move after the current move. So I believe yes, `matrix.sequels` should include both "Matrix: Reloaded" and "Matrix: Revolutions" in order.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way could be using an ActiveRecord plugin like `acts_as_list` which allows you to define ordering between different items. You'd need to add a field to use as a scope, such as `saga`, so the order is defined within movies which belong to the same saga.

https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list

The plugin provides handy methods `lower_items` and `higher_items` which would work like the `sequels` and `prequels` methods you are looking for,